# Hover menu items

Tags: javascript, html, menu, hover, jquery-animate

help me implement a hover menu.
The bottom line is that when hovering to a menu item, the red circle smoothly approaches the hover item. When the cursor leaves the point, the circle smoothly rises to its coordinates.
Thanks in advance.

```css
nav{
  position: relative;
}
.circle{
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-blick;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.menu{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  height: audo;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-blick;
  list-style: none;  
}
.menu li{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <ul class="menu">
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 3</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxcHT.png)

Comment: Are you willing to use javascript or are you trying to achieve it with pure CSS?

Comment: sorry if i understand it correct, you want the red dot to move towards the menu item if you hover over the menu item?

Comment: What means - `the circle smoothly rises to its coordinates`? What coordinates are we talking about?

Comment: I need to implement this in javascript, the circle should return after the cursor has been removed from the menu to its position from the start

Answer (score 0):

**How this script works:**

Takes all the `<li>` items in the `id="menu"` and sets them to "Event Listener" for `mouseover` and `mouseout`

When hovering over a `<li>` element, the script takes its position from top and height. These coordinates are passed to the `#circle` element as an inline style.

When the mouse cursor is `mouseout` from the `<li>` elements, the inline style is removed and the red point returns to its original position.

*You can change the movement speed from CSS `transition: 0.8s;`*

```js
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
var li = menu.getElementsByTagName('li');
var dot = document.getElementById('circle');

for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        setAnimation(this);
    });

    li[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
        dot.setAttribute('style', '');
    });
}

function setAnimation(el) {
    var pos = el.offsetTop;
    var h = el.offsetHeight;
    dot.setAttribute('style', 'top:' + (pos + h / 2) + 'px;');
}
```

```css
nav {
    position: relative;
}

#circle {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    display: inline-blick;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);

    -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: 0.8s;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

#menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    height: audo;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-blick;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div id="circle"></div>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
        <li>Menu 4</li>
        <li>Menu 5</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by several ways. I have created some methods below. You can also add animations in the given code.
I am considering the div `<div class="circle"></div>`
is not mandatory to place before `<ul>` Tag

```js
function chbg(elem,color) {
elem.firstChild.style.backgroundColor=color;
}
var circle = '<div class="circle" style="background-color: red;"></div>';
var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu2')[0];
for (var i = 0; i < menu.children.length; i++) {
    menu.children[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
      this.innerHTML =this.innerHTML.replaceAll(circle,'')
    });

    menu.children[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
if(this.innerHTML.indexOf(circle)==-1)
       this.innerHTML =this.innerHTML+circle
    });
}
```

```css
nav{
  position: relative;
}

.circle{
  float:left;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-blick;
  border-radius: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.menu, .menu2, .menu3{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  height: audo;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-blick;
  list-style: none;  
}

.menu3 li:before { 
opacity:0;
content: ''; 
background-color: red;
float:left;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-blick;
  border-radius: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  }
  .menu3 li:hover:before{
  opacity:1;
  }
```

```html
<h1>method 1 using javascript</h1>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
  <li onmouseover="chbg(this,'red')" onmouseout="chbg(this,'white')"><div class="circle"></div>Menu 1</li>
  <li onmouseover="chbg(this,'red')" onmouseout="chbg(this,'white')"><div class="circle"></div>Menu 2</li>
  <li onmouseover="chbg(this,'red')" onmouseout="chbg(this,'white')"><div class="circle"></div>Menu 3</li>
</ul>
</nav>

<h1>method 2 using javascript</h1>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu2">
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 3</li>
</ul>
</nav>

<h1>method 3 using CSS</h1>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu3">
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 3</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```